# European route E4 in geodata format

Tags: data

Has anybody locate any kml, shp or gpx file with the complete European trail E4 ?

Lots of google search navigates me to nowhere ...

Answer (score 1):

Far from being complete, Openstreetmap has over 6000 km of the trail:

http://hiking.waymarkedtrails.org/en/relation/371740#

The GPX button should give you the data in GPX format.